# Fancybox links and select are not woking

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I wonder why link doing nothing if I click on it and select close automatically just right after it was opened.

Here is my **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RyTcS/229/)**

To call fancybox window automatically, I use this code: `$('#task').fancybox().trigger('click');​`

How to fix it?

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve and what is the problem?

Comment: @roomcays select element isn't work, it close automatically. And link doesn't work at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confuse about the use of fancybox.

First, you need to set the `class="fancybox"` to the anchor `<a>`, not to the `<div>` parent container of both, the anchor and the target (`select`).

Second, the target should be a different element, not the root (this `href="/"` doesn't make sense in your case), which contains the launcher and the target.

Third, it would be a good idea to set the proper html structure to the `select` element, which is inside of a `form` tag.

See [this forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DmaUf/) for a working sample.